# Como isolar um "ambiente" no Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estou com o seguinte problema: trabalho em um local onde utilizamos um programa de edição de imagens bem específico que só funciona no Ubuntu 14.04 (o programa se chama **Register**).

De vez em quando, o programa para de funcionar parcialmente em algum computador, sem motivo aparente. Estou achando que o problema possa ser os usuários dos computadores, que instalam outros programas que acabam alterando a versão de algumas dependências que o Register necessita (libc6, libstdc++6, imagemagick, perl, libgl1-mesa-glx, e libglu1-mesa).

Para resolver isso, estava pensando se não há como criar um ambiente isolado para instalar o Register, algo tipo os ambientes em Python. Nesse ambiente eu instalaria somente o programa e as dependências que ele precisa. Porém, não daria para ser um container do Docker, como já haviam me sugerido, pois o funcionamento do Register se dá via terminal, por exemplo: "$ register imagem1 imagem2 imagemsaida" e não ficaria muito fácil de utilizar, visto que os usuários do programa tem quase nenhum conhecimento em linux.

Comment: Acho que esta pergunta está fora do escopo do site. Mas, tentando ajudar, por que não cria uma VM com o VirtualBox ou algum relacionado?

Comment: Acho que ela se enquadra no escopo por se tratar basicamente de gerenciamento de dependências de um software, mas concordo com as pessoas que dizem que Docker pode ser a solução; se complicar muito como acha que vai, valeria a pena criar uma interface para rodar na máquina que executasse os comandos dentro do Docker.

Comment: Eu nao sei como fazer, mas sei que o [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) faz isso